# how to change the status of record i am retrieving

Tags: php, mysql, database, scripting, server

i want to change the status of the message which i am retrieving.
consider a MySQL database with three column message,username and status.
[image: Database looks like this]

from this table i am retrieving the message which are all having the status 1.
for example i am retrieving the message of user1 which status is 1 after retrieving that message i want to change the status of that message to 0. only the user1 message status not the others. How do i do it? Someone please answer.....

Comment: update message_user2 set status=0 where username='user1' and status=1    ... will update 2 rows by the way, if that is what you mean

Comment: you probably want an auto_inc id in that table to drive it

Comment: well first off re-read your question. We don't know if you want to set to 0 just the 1st message for user1, or both of them. Then, if you just want to update one of them, using a where clause using the Message='hey there' that @EuphoriaGrogi had in his first take at it, means (probably) a non-index search. So you need a PK on a column id. It is basic table design

Comment: You need composite indexes to get to (user,status) etc, and this is not a tutorial site in little text windows. You should spend a few hours on tutorials

Comment: you should ask questions related to gneric problem. What you want to do is not strictly related to the "status".  A more appropriate title could be "how to update a record on mysql database". I suggest you to read this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement

```
UPDATE message_user2 
SET status = 0 
WHERE Username = 'user1'
```

Comment: i can simply change the value. But what i want is after getting the record i want to change the value.

Comment: so you want a select to do an update too ? @karthikeyan

Comment: then as Drew said add primary key in your table, so we can reference it easily

Comment: i want to select a record in the database while retrieving that record i want to change the status value of that record

Comment: that is called a Stored Proc. Select doesn't do that on its own

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE message_user2
SET message_user2.status = 0 
WHERE Username IN '(SELECT Username FROM message_user2 WHERE Username = user1)';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)
SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 username FROM message_user2 WHERE username='user1' and status=1)`

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'Update message_user2 set status=0 where username='+@name
    EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT 'Updated value: ' + @name
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 username FROM message_user2 WHERE username='user1' and status=1 )
END
SELECT * from message_user2 where status=0 and  username='user1' 
GO